# Material node group will only work on the original object it was placed on, not if it is applied to another object

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

I recently did the BlenderGuru puddle tutorial and downloaded the example node group.

When I plug the maps into the original plane, the material works fine, but when I apply the material to any other object, it does not work.

[image]

Just the standard materials come through. It's as if the node group in being bypassed on any other geometry other than the original plane.

Anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your file, with the original object and the one that doesn't worrk? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please see attached file
https://we.tl/t-OwHMkYQJE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've vertex painted your original plane and used the color attribute as a mask in your node setup, as seen in the image below. If you want your new object to get the same effect it also needs a color attribute called *Col*, so subdivide your plane, switch to *Vertex Paint* mode, paint and give the same name to the new color attribute:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Never really looked into vertex painting. I'll bare this in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: make sure that you've subdivided your plane, vertex paint paints the vertices ;)